# Pull records from orders table for the current week

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I have a table with the following info...

```
Id | orderNumber | orderDate | customerId
```

`orderDate` is a MySQL datetime field and the current day, month, year and time is inserted into the database at the time the record is written.

So my question is how would I pull a list of orders for a certain day of this current week. My goal is to use the google charts API to make a chart for **"This Week's Sales"** that says something like:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                      ['Day', 'Sales'],
                      ['Mon',  1],
                      ['Tue',  0],
                      ['Wed',  4],
                      ['Thurs',  3],
                      ['Fri',  0],
                    ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's do exactly what you want:

```
SELECT
    WEEKDAY(`datetime_field`) AS `week_day`,
    COUNT(*) AS `sale_count`
FROM `orders`
WHERE YEARWEEK(`datetime_field`) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY `week_day`
ORDER BY `week_day` ASC;
```

**This returns a set of records with `week_day` and `sale_count`.** [Learn more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday). Use `NOW()` if you use local datetime or use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` if you play by GMT.

*Do keep in mind I don't know your database name or the fields' names. You need to fill those in.*

**WORKING EXAMPLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OrderDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `OrderValue` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`)
);

INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('1', '2012-10-29 14:02:19', '100.00');
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('2', '2012-10-30 14:02:19', '123.00');
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('3', '2012-10-31 14:02:19', '103.00');
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('4', '2012-11-01 14:02:19', '232.00');
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('5', '2012-11-02 14:02:19', '321.00');
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('6', '2012-11-03 14:02:19', '154.00');
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('7', '2012-11-04 14:02:19', '112.00');
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('8', '2012-10-29 14:02:19', '100.00');

SELECT
    WEEKDAY(`OrderDate`) AS `week_day`,
    COUNT(*) AS `sales_count`,
    SUM(`OrderValue`) AS `sales_value`
FROM `orders`
WHERE YEARWEEK(`OrderDate`) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY `week_day`
ORDER BY `week_day` ASC;
```

This is SQL to create a table, add 1 order per day for this week but 2 on Monday. And the query to fetch the report.

**AND HERE'S** [**SQLFIDDLE.COM** SAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/a5455/1/0).

Comment: ok so this works to pull this weeks like you said:
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE YEARWEEK(`date_field`) = YEARWEEK(NOW());

How would I pull just the monday of this week. I would like to run 7 seperate queries so I have 7 seperate says of orders, like:

$mondayOrders, $tuesdayOrders, etc. That way I can say monday has 3 orders, tuesday has 5 orders, wednesday has zero orders, etc.

Comment: @DanielWhite Try the query first please. It does the grouping internally. No need for 7 queries. Just one. It uses GROUP BY. Test it (it returns up to 7 rows) after you set the right table name and column name instead of date_field.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work for me. When I use your first suggestion, it does work. The second suggestion doesn't return any records and I have tried changing the order date to every day around today and it doesn't pull anything.

Comment: @DanielWhite I tested locally on a table that has dates and it works. Can you paste your DDL here (SHOW CREATE TABLE)? I want to see your table columns and change the code. And make sure you test in a MySQL client like WorkBench or Navicat... not in PHP... or paste the PHP code too here just to make sure you're doing it right. The mysql fetch part.