# Show MySQL data in table with subsets of data

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I am trying to retreive records from a mysql table and display them in a table. I can do it with individual queries like this for each cell:

```
$sql = "SELECT Sum(combined_data.`List Price`) AS total_dollar_amount, Count(combined_data.sysid) AS total_units FROM combined_data
WHERE 
combined_data.`Zip Code` = 07675
AND combined_data.`Office Primary Board ID` = 'W' 
AND combined_data.`List Price` BETWEEN 0 AND 99999";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$link); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { // echo these strings to cells
$res_07675_0_99999_amount = $row['total_dollar_amount'];
$res_07675_0_99999_total_units = $row['total_units'];
$res_07675_0_99999_percent = ($res_07675_0_99999_amount / $total_volume) *100;
$res_07675_0_99999_percent = round($res_07675_0_99999_percent, 2);
    }
```

However, I would prefer to see if this could be done in a query.

Pulling all records from zip 07675, then use subset of the data by the column heading value range (0-99,000 then 100,000-199,00 etc.), (1) add the total of the subset for display, (2) count the # of values in the subset (# on mkt), then (3) calculate the (% of mkt) which is the total volume from all zip codes in all price ranges.

And, when done, being able to have it sorted by volume range ($) in each column.

I am not versed in mysql queries of this complexity and not sure if I am even going in the right direction to accomplish this. (currently reporting is done in Excel)

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated. Or is there a app that would help create this code?

Thanks.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 1):

**Learn about [GROUP BY in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html).** Allows you to easily create reports by grouping records into subsets and then extract data from those subsets.

*It's most likely what you need.*

Also see this sample answer as it might give you a hint:
[Pull records from orders table for the current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115130/pull-records-from-orders-table-for-the-current-week-php-mysql-codeigniter/13115178#13115178)