# mysql date show results today/yesterday/week

Tags: php, mysql, unix, date, time

I am retrieving data from a table and show the total SUM of entries. What I want to do is to show the total SUM of entries made on today's date, yesterday and this month. The table is using the unix timestamp format (e.g. 1351771856 for example).

Currently I am using this line to show todays results:

```
AND comment_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 3600";
```

but that gives me just the entries for the last 24 hours.

**Example**: So let's say its Friday, 17:00 PM - it gives me the count from Thursday 17:00 PM to Friday 17:00 PM

**What I want** is to get the results for

- Thursday 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 (yesterday in this case)
- the results for today (00:00:00 - 23:59:59)
- and last week, results that start on Monday, 00:00:00 until "today" (in this case Friday).

I couldn't find a way in the MySQL documentation to achieve this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `real` values?

Comment: for example: comment_date = $today or comment_date = $yesterday, comment_date = $this_month

Comment: there is no "today" or "yesterday" variables, you have to pick a certain period using timestamp or other date types (or mysql date difference if you use datetime). Your approach is the only way to see the results I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This mysql code should work for you:

```
// Today
AND DATE(from_unixtime(comment_date)) = CURRENT_DATE

// Yesterday
AND DATE(from_unixtime(comment_date)) =  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY)

// This week
AND YEARWEEK(from_unixtime(comment_date), 1) =  YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE, 1)

// This month
AND YEAR(from_unixtime(comment_date)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(from_unixtime(comment_date)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: The only thing left is calculating the "this week" by starting from monday

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson , I tried it, but for some reason using '@now' gives me an "500 internal server error"

Comment: Updated my answer with this week

Comment: @vinculis You need to check year on WEEK too not to get the same week last year. Also, you need to pass '1' as a second parameter to get start of week on monday.

Comment: Hey, I had to wait until 00:00 here to test "yesterdays" function. It's seems that there is a problem with the timezone, because i am getting yesterday's results in the todays field and the "yesterday" results are from the day before yesterday. My server is in the US, I am in Asia. I tried putting "date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Chongqing');" into the php, yet it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: is there any way to add an time offset into this line "**WHERE DATE(from_unixtime(comment_date)) = CURRENT_DATE";** ? Or is there an easier approach?

Comment: Have you tried `CONVERT_TZ()`? For example: `WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(from_unixtime(comment_date)), 'GMT', 'MET') = CURRENT_DATE";` I don't know exact timezones, you can change `GMT` and `MET` by your required timezones. More info about this MySql function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: thanks @vinculis for your answer, yet now i get an error message **Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'CONVERT_TZ'** that's my query : ** $sql = "SELECT COUNT(store_id) AS cfftime_stores FROM ".GUESTBOOK_TABLE." WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(from_unixtime(comment_date)), 'GMT', 'CST') = CURRENT_DATE";** .. again many thanks for your support!

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. Change to `DATE(CONVERT_TZ(from_unixtime(comment_date), 'GMT', 'CST')) = CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: hm, no error now but it shows me 0 entries, and I just made one new entry (for today/ 03.11.2012 01:51 CST) - do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Okay after looking over i found out that i have no default timezone set in my php.ini - might be a dumb question, but how to find it out the server time/timezone without stating it prior? E.g. how to find out from which timezone i want to convert to CST ? :D

Comment: Okay, if someone else has this issues, i solved my problem by using numbers: **'+08:00', '-08:00'))** instead of UTC/CST etc. @vinculis, thanks again for your support

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
AND comment_date > date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

*See my answer here, I think it's quite related.*

[Pull records from orders table for the current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115130/pull-records-from-orders-table-for-the-current-week-php-mysql-codeigniter/13115178#13115178)

**Consider getting intimate with** [**MySQL's GROUP BY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html). You will most likely need to know this if you use MySQL.